# Java "peer" socket for peer to peer communication

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, p2p

In Java, you can use `Socket` and `ServerSocket` to get a bidirectional channel for communication between two processes. But only one of them has to have the ServerSocket and is treated as "the server" and the other one as "the client", being the server the one which has to be available first. So, is there a way to make both peers the same code? I mean, in a client-server application, the server has to wait for clients:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
```

whereas the client has to connect to the server:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
```

And if there is no active server, the client code fails.

My question is whether is there a way to make both peers use the client code to wait for another host to appear, so that it does not matter which peer arrived first.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? It seems to be a XY problem! Please describe what you are developing?

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful  Maybe it is an XY problem. I'm developing a game, but my question is just for curiosity

Comment: Did you try JXTA framework ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In peer-to-peer applications each peer is both a client and a server. Multiple threads are usually used to make peers be able to listen to incoming connections as well as establishing new ones to other peers. Thus the code is the same for all peers.